# Excluding rows that match a list of characters

Tags: r

I have a big problem, in my dataframe I have people that are hypertensive, but dont use medication, and people that use medication however have "normal" blood pressure.

For that, I've created a list with all medications by Brazilian Guideline of Hypertension. It worked, but I generated NA values in people that use antihypertensive medication and NA values in people that didnt report use o medication, therefore if I use complete.cases I'm excluding healthy people and sick people.

Here I import data from a SPSS file, that contain the drugs that people reported in the questionaire

```
     library(memisc)

     setwd("C:/Users/Rafael/Documents/RStudio")

     Med<- as.data.set(spss.system.file("medicamentos_fase4a_pro_saude.sav"))

     Med <- Med[c(2,5)]

     Med <- as.data.frame(Med)

     names(Med)[names(Med) == 'quest'] <- 'Quest'

     View(Med)
```

Medication List

```
     ListedMeds <- c("diuréticos", "carvedilol", "olmesartana", "tiazídicos", "clortalidona", "hidroclorotiazida", "indapamida", "bumetamida", "furosemida", "piretanida", "amilorida ", "espironolactona", "triantereno ", "antihipertensivo", "alfametildopa", "clonidina", "guanabenzo", "moxonidina", "doxazosina", "prazosina",...)

     for(m in ListedMeds){ Med = Med[ !grepl(m, Med$med_rec), ] } 

     library(plyr) #### I use plyr because in the dataframe people that reported more than 1 medication was duplicated, so there were 1 row for each medication from the same person

     Med <- ddply(Med, .(Quest), summarize, Rem = paste (med_rec, collapse = ", "))
```

Merging Med, DF with medications and number of Questionaire and my DF with Blood pressure results.

```
     DFPA <- merge (DFPA, Med, by = "Quest", all = TRUE)

     DFPA <- subset(DFPA, select = c(Quest, PASM, PADM, PAM, PP, CCor, CGI, Sexo, FEtária, HAS))
```

Excluding NA values:

```
     DFPA <- DFPA[complete.cases(DFPA), ]

     DFPA <- subset(DFPA, select = c(Quest,PASM, PADM, PAM, PP, CCor, CGI, Sexo, FEtária, HAS))`
```

I know that I'm not doing nothing in the end, because I'm excluding everyone that has a NA, and it can be a healthy or a sick person. So I wanna know how to exclude all people that match the listed medication.

ps: The list "ListedMeds" contains medications from people that said they use in a regular basis some medication. So, in this cohort I have 4000 people, I've excluded some people based in some parameters, resulting in 2854 people. When I merge Meds with DFPA, the number becomes 3011, however a lot of these people only have information at the column Rem and are NA at the other columns.

ps2: Would it be possible to create a new dataframe with people that were excluded from DFPA, because said that they use antihypertensive medication? Because I think I could resolve the problem, but more than 1000 people were excluded, however I think this number is wrong.

```
` str(DFPA)
'data.frame':   2854 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Quest  : Factor w/ 3041 levels "0001","0002",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 ...
 $ PASM   : num  116 128 107 112 103 122 112 99 123 120 ...
 $ PADM   : num  64 86 58 73 69 84 72 62 73 77 ...
 $ PAM    : num  81 100 74 86 80 97 85 74 90 91 ...
 $ PP     : num  52 42 49 39 34 38 40 37 50 43 ...
 $ Age    : num  60 52 53 47 44 61 54 54 33 55 ...
 $ Color  : Factor w/ 3 levels "B","P","PD": 1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 ...
 $ Educ   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1º","2º","3º": 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 ...
 $ Sex    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ FEtária: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "A"<"B"<"C"<"D": 4 3 3 3 2 4 3 3 1 3 ...
 $ HAS    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "N"<"P"<"H1"<"H2": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 ... `

`    > str(Med)
    List of 2
     $ Quest: chr [1:2189] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
     $ Rem  : chr [1:2189] "cloreto de sódio, dimenidrato, escopolamina, 
    fitoterápico, omeprazol, ramipril+anlodipino, sertralina" "colágeno, 
    dipirona, vitamina e suplemento mineral" "homeopatia" "vitamina e suplemento 
    mineral" ...
`
```

Sample:

```
> mysample
     Quest PASM PADM PAM PP Age Color Educ Sex FEtária HAS
133   0133  130   84  99 46  56    PD   1º   M       C   P
1641  1685  146   84 105 62  57    PD   1º   M       C  H1
482   0483  122   78  93 44  64     P   2º   F       D   P
2260  2305  118   78  91 40  54     P   3º   F       C   N
1140  1184  114   70  85 44  63     B   2º   M       D   N
1527  1571  168   98 121 70  56     P   2º   M       C  H2
941   0983  116   73  87 43  65    PD   2º   M       D   N
506   0507  134   90 105 44  60     B   3º   M       D   P
2676  2722  100   60  73 40  50     B   3º   M       C   N
326   0327  106   78  87 28  66     P   2º   F       D   N
```

Comment: It will help us to help you if you provide a small portion of the dataset you want to change. We can't run any of your code and see for ourselves this merging. Can you come up with an example using dput() on a subset of your dataset? (and then pasting the output into your edited question)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that dput was too strange, then I used normal sample. If you think it's needed, I can post ir here.